# Don't Change Route Unless Form Valid

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm using Angular with Typescript (Definition: [angular.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts)) with the following setup

- Controller1

  - Form1
- Controller2

  - Form2
- ShareService - A service which contains a model shared by both Controller1 and controller2.

I have a single save button which will post the model from the ShareService and persist any changes.

How I can prevent the user from navigating to Form2 if the current Form1 is invalid and vice versa?

I'm using ngRoute for my application routing. I'm also using the controller as syntax over the scope.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms you can use ng-valid or use custom code for validation on the ng-click event on your submit button.

Comment: How can I tie that in with the route change though? I don't want the user to change route/views unless the current form is valid. Is there nothing built into the routing?

Comment: Programmatically change the route, on the ng-click event you can trigger the route change only if the form is valid else ng-click does nothing or shows some error message.